# Sending Mail from Web App to Google Apps won't work - internal routing? VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, smtp, routing, g-suite

I've got a web application, www.mysuperwebapp.com, which sends out emails for various reasons - the contact us page is a good example.

I am using google apps on the domain and I've setup a google apps group, Support (support@mysuperwebapp.com), which I want the emails from the contact us page to go to.

But the emails don't seem to be sending...

I thought it could be that the groups security is a little tighter than normal email, so I change the contact us email to go to charles@mysuperwebapp.com - but they still didn't appear.

So I'm guessing that it has something to do with internal routing and the messages aren't leaving the server/network at all. Eg Sending an email from the mysuperwebapp.com computer to a mysuperwebapp.com email address.

I put an entry into the hosts file for 123.123.123.123 mysuperwebapp.com but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Also, there doesn't seem to be anything of interest in the event log.

What do I need to do? Or what do I need to get my VPS hoster to do?

TIA,
Charles

Ps. The VPS is a Windows 2008 box with IIS7 and the default SMTP (IIS6?) server. The web app is ASP.NET MVC - not that that should matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my own bad... during the setup of the SMTP server I had added an alias for my domain, so they weren't getting out because of that.

I've removed the alias and it's all working fine and dandy again!